# Fieldset e legend com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma div que após colocar um fieldset e uma legend, ela diminuiu de tamanho.

[image: Legend]

Eu preciso que fique assim:

[image: Legend]

```css
::ng-deep .dx-datagrid-headers .dx-datagrid-content {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 500;
}

::ng-deep .dx-datagrid-headers .dx-datagrid-table .dx-row>td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #337ab7;
}

::ng-deep .dx-datagrid-pager {
  border-top: 1px double #ddd;
}

.second-group {
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.15);
  padding: 20px;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  /* controla a distancia entre os elementos e a borda */
  margin: 15px;
  /* margem para alinhar o fieldset com o restante do grid */
}

legend {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

E meu HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card col-12 padd-left0 padd-right0">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block" style="display: inline;">
        <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="adicionarSolicitacaoPagamento()" [formGroup]="conciliacaoBancariaForm">

          <br />

          <div class="row second-group">

            <!-- <fieldset>
              <legend> Filtro por data</legend> -->

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Conta Corrente </label>
                <dx-select-box placeholder="Selecione Conta..." [items]="contasCorrente" displayExpr="descricao" valueExpr="id" [searchEnabled]="true" formControlName="contaCorrenteId">
                </dx-select-box>
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId">
                    <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId"></p>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoInicial">Data Emissão Inicial</label>
                <dx-date-box type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" formControlName="dataEmissaoInicial" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial">
                    <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial"></p>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoFinal">Data Emissão Final</label>
                <dx-date-box [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" formControlName="dataEmissaoFinal" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal">
                    <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal"></p>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <button type="button" style="margin-top: 27px" class="btn btn-block btn-success" (click)="filtrarConciliacao()">
                  <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Filtrar </button>
            </div>
            <!-- </fieldset> -->
          </div>

          <br />
```

Comment: Cara aqui ficou assim http://prntscr.com/ncoru9 deve ter algum outro CSS ai que está interferindo no fieldset. Vc usa mesmo o Bootstrap 3 né? Ou está usando o 4?

Comment: desculpe Hugo, estou usando o 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o fieldset com o `width` de 100%,  e coloque ele acima da `div`com a classe `row`, como abaixo:

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  /* controla a distancia entre os elementos e a borda */
  margin: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  /* margem para alinhar o fieldset com o restante do grid */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="card col-12 padd-left0 padd-right0">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block" style="display: inline;">
                <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="adicionarSolicitacaoPagamento()" [formGroup]="conciliacaoBancariaForm">

                    <br />

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend> Filtro por data</legend> -->
                        <div class="row second-group">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Conta Corrente </label>
                                    <dx-select-box placeholder="Selecione Conta..." [items]="contasCorrente" displayExpr="descricao" valueExpr="id" [searchEnabled]="true" formControlName="contaCorrenteId">
                                    </dx-select-box>
                                    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId">
                    <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.contaCorrenteId"></p>
                  </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoInicial">Data Emissão Inicial</label>
                                    <dx-date-box type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" formControlName="dataEmissaoInicial" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
                                    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial">
                    <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoInicial"></p>
                  </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="dataEmissaoFinal">Data Emissão Final</label>
                                    <dx-date-box [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" type="date" width="100%" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" formControlName="dataEmissaoFinal" (onValueChanged)="definirValor($event)"></dx-date-box>
                                    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal">
                    <p [innerHTML]="displayMessage.dataEmissaoFinal"></p>
                  </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <button type="button" style="margin-top: 27px" class="btn btn-block btn-success" (click)="filtrarConciliacao()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Filtrar </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <br />
```

Comment: cara assim cada datebox fica em uma linha... [link] (https://prnt.sc/ncowwm)

Comment: Entendi, coloquei um ajuste na resposta para esse caso.